# Spring Cloud AWS InstantiationException thrown when using @Autowire

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, reflection, annotations, spring-cloud

I like the the ability to use constructors to add dependencies. Especially autowiring those dependencies.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Qualifier("bean-id") Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

}
```

What I'm finding is that the Spring Cloud AWS framework throws an "InstantiationException" if the "Dependency" class above happens to be a class which is passed to a Workflow worker and is missing a default, empty constructor.

concrete example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final DependencyWorkflowClientExternalFactory clientFactory;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Qualifier("bean-id") DependencyWorkflowClientExternalFactory clientFactory) {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
}

public class WorkflowInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowWorker workflowWorker; //assume wired with correct credentials    

    public WorkflowInitialiser() {
         init();
    }

    public init() {
        workflowWorker.addWorkflowImplementationType(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

the above fails with:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mypackage.MyClass
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
```

I have to do something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean-id")
    private Dependency dependency; 

    public MyClass() {
    }
}
```

The question is:

Is it possible in the current release of the Spring Cloud framework to use the @Autowire annotation on a constructor? Is it a requirement that the annotation is added to the instance field?

I ask (and assume "yes") because Workflow workers take a class types, rather than instantiations of objects for their implementations of workflows.

As a secondary question:

Why do ActivityWorkers take instances of an object but WorkflowWorkers take classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is actually not related to Spring Cloud AWS but AWS Flow Framework for Java.

You are using the "default" WorkflowWorker which instantiates workflow implementations as POJOs. Therefore your class MyClass is not created as a Spring bean but as a POJO.

You should use the SpringWorkflowWorker provided by the AWS Flow Framework for a better integration with Spring. For more information, have a look at the [AWS Flow Framework documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.spring) explaining the integration with Spring.